# new Boolean(name) always returns true

Tags: javascript

```js
let name = window.prompt("Please Enter Your Name ");
let age = parseInt(window.prompt("Please Enter Your age "));

const nameCheck = new Boolean(name);
const ageCheck = new Boolean(age);

if ( nameCheck && ageCheck )
{
   console.log(`Hi ${name}, you were born in ${2020 - age}`)
}
else
{
   alert("You either entered no name, or your age was not a number");
}
```

The if-block always evaluates to true and executes even if I intentionally enter an empty string or a letter for the age. I thought an empty string has to evaluate to false when converted to `Boolean` ?

Comment: you could instead use `const nameCheck = !!name;`

Comment: NameCheck and ageCheck are objects therefore they are evaluated to true. To your code works do not use the Boolean constructor but the Boolean function, I mean just remove the new keyword.

Comment: Thanks, removing the "new" really works !!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Boolean` doesn't do what you think it does. It's an object, and objects are always truthy:

```
> typeof new Boolean(false)
"object"
> if (new Boolean(false)) console.log("It's true!");
It's true!
```

To convert a value to a primitive `boolean` type instead, a common way is to negate it twice:

```
const nameCheck = !!name;
```

You can also invoke `Boolean` as a function, but I'd stay away from that because it's rather confusing that it doesn't return an actual `Boolean`:

```
const nameCheck = Boolean(name);
```

Comment: You can find this in the MDN documentation too.
"Any object of which the value is not undefined or null, including a Boolean object whose value is false, evaluates to true when passed to a conditional statement. "

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

Answer (score 2):

[Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) is an object wrapper which always returns truthy value. You can run `.valueOf()` to get wrapped value or get rid of `new`:

```js
let x = new Boolean("");

console.log(x === false);
console.log(x.valueOf() === false);

let y = Boolean("");

console.log(y === false);
```

Comment: Or just drop the `new`. Although `Boolean("false")` or `new Boolean("false")` will always produce a primitive `true`.

Comment: @VLAZ which of course is confusing for someone new or coming to JS world from different language. Thanks for your comment !